# Evaluate the limit when $\frac{x + y}{x^2 + 1}$ approaches $(0,0)$ using the epsilon delta definition

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

The limit is $0$, but we have to prove it using the epsilon-delta definition. How do we make the epsilon-delta relation for this?

I found that the limits for the function itself is $0$ by finding the limits on $y$ axis( where $x=0$), on $x$ axis( where $y=0$), when $y=x$, when $y=x^3$, where the limit was always $0$ therefore the limit is $0$.

Comment: "...therefore the limit is $0$" That is a dangerous conclusion and it doesn't follow from the paths, of course since maybe with some path that you don't consider the story is different. That is why the paths do not allow us to conclude about the existence of a limit but nonexistence yes. Now, returning to your question.  Can you show your work using the definition?

Comment: Ok, yea i wanted to say that we have assume that the limit is 0 for now and then use the epsilon delta definition to then prove it. thx for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in A. P.'s comment, the limit being zero along any given path is necessary but not sufficient. If you want to prove this in general, use inequalities, in particular that $x^2 + 1 \geq 1$ for all $x$ and thus $\left|\frac{x+y}{x^2+1}\right| \leq \left| x+y \right|$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: how do we use this in the epsilon-delta definition though?

Comment: you need to show that if $||(x,y)|| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is small that $|x+y|$ will be small as well. That is, given $\epsilon > 0$, find $\delta$ (probably in terms of $\epsilon$) so that if $||(x,y)|| < \delta$ then $|x+y| < \epsilon$.